# Chrome not taking effect of css overriding

Tags: css, google-chrome

So I have tried manipulating the style within the chrome inspector and copying it directly into my stylesheet, but it is not reflected when I run it again on chrome. The code runs fine on firefox otherwise and also if I manually input the change in chrome inspector.

Not sure what the issue is as I've tried adding the !important as well and making sure of the hierarchy is of the right order.

css code

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}
.is-invalid .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid #dc3545 !important;
}
```

html

```
<div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between {{ $errors->first('contact_name', 'is-invalid')  }}">
    <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
    <span class="message">{{ $errors->first('contact_name', ':message') }}</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="e.g. John Smith">
</div>
```

I have also cleared the cache and checked to see the source file that everything is as per updated. It is just not showing on the result ONLY in chrome

Comment: Could it be a cached response?

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache beforehand and it returns the same result

Comment: That's odd. Try going to the file in the sources panel of the inspector and seeing if the changes you made are there.

Comment: try ctrl+shift+r

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it needs hard reload.

Hold down Ctrl and click the Reloadbutton. Or, Hold down Ctrl and press F5.

`Ctrl+F5`

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear the cache using the chrome debugging tools. Press `F12` then select `Application` then select `Clear Storage` make sure the `cache` checkboxes are checked, then click the `clear site data` button.

[image: Chrome Debugging]

Answer (score 0):

Try Hard Reload by right click on reload button.

[image]